# Using Python to discriminate Personal Geodatabases and MS Access Databases

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-10.0, personal-geodatabase, ms-access

I need to list a server's geodatabases, to analyze and process them. My users are however creating both personal geodatabases and MS Access geodatabases.

Listing `mdb` files reports both types of databases, I woudl like to narrow the list down to **geo**databases only.
The boolean workspace property `is_geodatabase` would be exactly what I need to use, as it indicates whether a database is spatially enabled or not. Unfortunately, this property is only available for SDE databases.

I am using ArcGIS 10.0. and the script below. The choice was made to list `mdb` files by extension using `os.walk()` rather than `arcpy.ListWorkspaces()` for speed of process, and because `ListWorkspaces` retrieves MS Access databases anyway.
How can I amend my script to report *only* personal geodatabases, and not flat MS acess databases?

```
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(analyzed_root_folder):          
    for x in files:        
        if x.lower().endswith(".mdb") == True:
            ext_mdb.append( os.path.join(path, x))
```

Comment: I have also tested using the `workspaceFactoryProgID` property of the Describe object (when describing non-geodatabase .mdb file) and it returned `esriDataSourcesGDB.AccessWorkspaceFactory.1` even though there is no geo repository inside. http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Workspace_properties/000v00000037000000/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check it with odbc and search if database contain table starting with GDB_

[image]

```
import pyodbc

db_file = "C:/path/to/my/database/MyDataBase.mdb"
user = ''
password = ''
odbc_conn_str = 'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=%s;UID=%s;PWD=%s' % \
                (db_file, user, password)
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(odbc_conn_str)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
if cursor.tables(table='GDB_GeomColums').fetchone():
   print('This is ArcGIS Personal Geodatabase')

del cursor 
cnxn.close()
```

Comment: do you know if a particular encoding is required for the connexion string? and/or how I can find this out? My dbfile variable is in iso-8859-1, as it is in French and I have to accomodate accentuated characters. I am getting encoding errors, even after deocoding db_file into unicode or recoding it into utf-8, or into the default codepage reported by my cmd window. Thanks!

Comment: you can change your console for work in output encoding or pass values by argv in client encoding to script. the script read your client encoding (forced by a param or auto detected) and your fonction can reencode your value to utf-8. if you speak french as me there is a good article by sam&max [encoding-en-python-une-bonne-fois-pour-toute](http://sametmax.com/lencoding-en-python-une-bonne-fois-pour-toute/)